# Changing jQuery drop down selection behavior when clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down that I found here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

HTML:

```
 <ul class="dropdown" tabindex="1">
    <li><a href="/user/profile">profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/user/logout">log out</a></li>
</ul>
```

At this point of the js:

```
    function DropDown(el) {
            this.dd = el;
            this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
            this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
            this.val = '';
            this.index = -1;
            this.initEvents();
        }

        DropDown.prototype = {
            initEvents : function() {
                var obj = this;

                obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
                    $(this).toggleClass('active');
                    return false;
                });

                obj.opts.on('click',function(){
                    var opt = $(this);
                    obj.val = opt.text();
                    obj.index = opt.index();
                    obj.placeholder.text('profile: ' + obj.val);
                });
            },
            getValue : function() {
                return this.val;
            },
            getIndex : function() {
                return this.index;
            }
        }

        $(function() {

            var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

            $(document).click(function() {
                // all dropdowns
                $('.wrapper-dropdown-1').removeClass('active');
            });

        });
```

When the dropdown items are selected text is being placed into the parent ul selection instead of going to the page I'd like it to.  Everything works fine with this simple dropdown I just need to disable the part that replaces the Link with the selected text.  I just want the anchor tags to works normally like any  would.

Error msg:

```
try
84      {
85          if ( ! class_exists($prefix.$controller))
86          {
87              throw new HTTP_Exception_404('The requested URL :uri was not     found on this server.',
88                                                      array(':uri' => $request->uri()));
89          }
90 
91          // Load the controller using reflection
92          $class = new ReflectionClass($prefix.$controller);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace this part with this...

```
obj.opts.on('click',function(){
                var opt = $(this);
                obj.val = opt.text();
                window.location.href=opt.data('link');
            });
```

And give all your `li's` a data attribute with the `href` / link where its going...

ie...

```
     <li data="http://newpage.html">New Page</li>
```

Unless your `li` elements have an `<a>` element inside of them, then you can probably just do something like this...

```
 obj.opts.on('click',function(){
                var opt = $(this);
                link = opt.closest('a').attr('href');
                window.location.href=link;
            });
```

Comment: That almost worked.  Except I'm getting a PHP error and with an "Undefined" message.  I updated the post with the HTML.

Comment: Lets see your HTML li elements though

Comment: I added my HTML to the original post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: just change the line window.location to window.location.href.  Originally I thought you were linking absolutely, but you're linking within your site, and just need to append pieces to the url. I edited my above answer above to show that.  Should work now, if not, its an error with your routing...in php or htaccess.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working.  I'm getting an "undefined" still.

Comment: Well thats got to do with your PHP and routing/htaccess/etc.  My answer was just to answer your question.  Which I did....the rest I cannot answer since I know nothing of your php code, and site structure.  Do the links work fine when you copy and paste them into a browser?